# python - ImportError: cannot import name Pool

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Code here:

```
from multiprocessing import pool
def worker(num):
    print 'Worker:', num
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

Sorry I am new to python. I am getting the below error whenever I try to import pool. It says something wrong with os.chdir(wdir) but I cant figure out what. Any help ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\z080302\Desktop\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
File "C:/Users/z080302/Desktop/Python_Projects/mp_test.py", line 18, in <module>
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
NameError: name 'multiprocessing' is not defined
```

Comment: Have you written your own file called multiprocessing? It might be trying to import that (which doesn't have a `pool` to import).

Comment: ok so i had created the multiprocessing file, which is why i think it was giving an error..i deleted that file now. but now it gives a name error..editing the original question

Comment: Can you provide us with the whole file? If it's too big copy-paste it into pastebin and post the link here

Comment: which file do you want me to share ? I am just running a small code.                 ` from multiprocessing import pool
def worker(num):
    print 'Worker:', num
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()`

Comment: I found the problem, all you have to do is to add import multiprocessing under from multiprocessing import pool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your code:

```
from multiprocessing import pool
def worker(num):
    print 'Worker:', num
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

You have to import the module multiprocessing to use multiprocessing.Process, you have only imported the function/class Pool from multiprocessing, so a simple fix would be:

```
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.pool
def worker(num):
    print 'Worker:', num
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

Comment: thanks..can you point me somewhere to learn how multiprocessing actually works ?? would be of great help

Comment: Certainly : http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing_intro.html , http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html

Answer (score 11):

Did you call your script 'multiprocessing.py'? Check your directory or file first... if yes -> Python will look for Pool in your script, which probably isn't there.(Rename it if exist) Sounds funny but it happens )

Comment: multiprocessing is a python library.. https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @StupidWolf,  Hi Wold, yes it is, but if you try to set your script name to multiprocessing.py it must not work , wait a min I will post a code .

Comment: from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

COUNT = 50000000
def countdown(n):
    while n>0:
        n -= 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    start = time.time()
    r1 = pool.apply_async(countdown, [COUNT//2])
    r2 = pool.apply_async(countdown, [COUNT//2])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    end = time.time()
    print('Time taken in seconds -', end - start)


and file name is multiprocessing.py

Comment: yes i understand that there might be a clash. Look carefully at the question, the OP did only "from multiprocessing import pool".. so he/she did not import multiprocessing directly. So most likely you would resolve that first.

Comment: @StupidWolf True

Answer (score 2):

You are importing only `pool` module from `multiprocessing` module.
So your interpreter is aware of `pool` only and not of `multiprocessing`

To resolve the problem, you must import `multiprocessing` and when you require the `pool` in code you can use it like `multiprocessing.pool`

```
multiprocessing
    |-- __init__.py
    |--Process
    |--Pool
    |--This_also
```

Like shown above, you are importing only `pool` and python doesn't know who the hell this multiprocessing and Process and This_also are.
Usually we have __ init __.py file in python package. A list in this file `all = ['pool.py','Process.py',.......'This_also']` contains all the modules contained in the package. So import * will import all the modules. Please go through the https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#

Answer (score 2):

If you have written a file called multiprocessing.py, it will try to import that first, which will mean it will not find Pool in it when you do "from multiprocessing import Pool".

multiprocessing is a module included in Python and has Pool in it, so if there are no conflicts the below should work:
"from multiprocessing import Pool"